# What happens if @2x image is available but not regular resolution image?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, retina-display

I'm wondering what will happen on a non-retina display device if only the @2x image is copied to the resources? Will it scale down the retina display image by 0.5 to accommodate the frame of the `UIImageView`?

I hope this isn't a silly question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The high resolution `@2x` images are not automatically down-sampled on non-retina devices.

Apple did not implement such feature because non-retina devices generally don't have enough memory to load and down-sample many high resolution images during initialization, it might cause trouble in case too many images need to be initialized.

**EDIT** *(Based on answer by WendiKidd)*

Non-retina devices will however down-size and display the high resolution `@2x` images, but **without** down-samling them, which causes poor image quality.

Comment: The image quality will be reduced in most cases, but it absolutely will use the @2x image if no regular image is available, which is what the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

I know for a fact that it will use the @2x images if no regular image is available, because I have tested it myself.  (Though I agree with David's comment--this is rather easy to test yourself.)  Now the image quality is decreased, because it's trying to resize an image that is much larger than the space you're trying to put it in.  But it absolutely will work.  Go give it a try and you'll see :)

Comment: I never claimed the `@2x` won't be displayed, I only claimed the images won't down-sampled. Updated my answer for clarity. Anyways, the fact remains that loading too many `@2x` images on non-retina devices might cause trouble. Adding down-sampled images improves image quality and performance.